# Oracle ESB, WS-AT and WCF

Tags: wcf, soa, esb, msdtc

Does any body tried to enable WS-AT usage between Oracle ESB and WCF web service?

At the moment I enabled WS-AT transactions on the MS DTC side, also I enabled usage of SSL for web services in weblogic JTA. However, I run with error: [EJB:010158]Illegal attempt to call EJBContext.setRollbackOnly() from an EJB that was not participating in a transaction.

Do we need to register SSL certificate in Weblogic in order to organize trusted connection between oracle soa and MS DTC?

Answer (score 0):

Today I'm going to share that we found answer to my question. Main thing which you should take into account that communication between Weblogic Transaction Coordinator and MSDTC are organized via SSL secured channel.
So, if you going to enable WS-AT between WCF and Oracle BPEL composite service you should take do following:

1. Prepare valid SSL certificates, one for Oracle Weblogic and one for workstation with MSDTC.
2. Import certificates to key stores on Weblogic and MSDTC servers.
3. Install [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=11310) on windows workstation:
4. [Configure WS-Atomic Transaction Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733943.aspx)
5. Enable SSL Listen Port at Weblogic.
6. [Configure Web service atomic transactions at Weblogic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/webservices/ConfigureAtomicTransactions.html)
7. In Weblogic set "Web Service Transactions Transport Security Mode" to "SSL Required", but you should uncheck "Web Service Transactions Issued Token Enabled".

When you did steps above you can enable WS-Atomic Transaction policies on WCF and BPEL sides and organize work between services in transactional way.